# Removing laravel 4.1 error messages in production site

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, error-handling

What I wonder is that whether I am able to close error messages in laravel 4.1 or not.

I have a project which has 3 environment: Production, beta and development. Is it possible to close error messages in production?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To not let your users see error messages, you have to:

1) Open your `app/config/app.php` and set

```
'debug' => false
```

2) Open your `app/start/global.php` and edit:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    Log::error($exception);

    return "whatever you need here!"; // <---- add a return command
});
```

3) This return line could be something like:

```
return Redirect::route('userErrorMessageRouteName');
```

or

```
return View::make('userErrorMessageView');
```